# « youtube.com/watch/ » end time

Tags: youtube

I distinctly remember having seen a parameter under « youtube.com/watch/ » which indicated when a video was to ***stop*** playing, much as the "t" parameter indicated the starting point.  It had a multi-letter name of some sort and took a value in seconds just as the "t" parameter did.  I have a few videos which will only play under « youtube.com/watch/ » and it strikes me as unfair that these videos can't be played with an ending point as well.  Whatever information you can provide will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is callend 'end'.

> This parameter specifies the time, measured in seconds from the start of the video, when the player should stop playing the video. The parameter value is a positive integer.
>
> Note that the time is measured from the beginning of the video and not from either the value of the start player parameter or the startSeconds parameter, which is used in YouTube Player API functions for loading or queueing a video.

Look [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) for all available parameters

Comment: Tried it for "youtube.com/watch/"...didn't work.  Ran through the limit like it wasn't there.  Tried it for "youtube.com/embed/" (the format used in examples)...wouldn't even play the video.  Other Ideas?

Comment: I think it is only working inside IFrames. The following example stops the player after 10 seconds.

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&amp;end=10&amp;origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0" style="
    display: block;
    z-index: 100000000;
    background-color: red;
"></iframe>

Comment: The video in question is the quieter portion of "I've Seen All Good People" by _Yes_ delimited via « https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xR4nUPviMQM&t=22&[end]=215 » ([end] is in braces because it doesn't seem to work in "/watch/" mode, and if I can't trust a video to behave in such a free-range mode like "/watch/", I can't foresee any better behavior in a framed mode like "/embed/"—especially if it doesn't work for the case in point anyway).  If you care to experiment a little—and don't mind a little link-editing—be my guest.